# Difference between Observable.create and Observable.createWithDisposable

Tags: rxjs

What is the difference between [`Observable.create`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/create.md) and `Observable.createWithDisposable`? I can't see the difference from the documentation or by looking at the source code.

Answer (score 2):

> [create] is an alias for the `createWithDisposable` method.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/d94905a34ba9953e705975acce136c0d0dbd495e/doc/api/core/operators/create.md

The two functions are interchangeable. `createWithDisposable` has been deprecated. You should use `create`.

`create` function can return a function that will be called when subscription is disposed (this function must be used to clean up).

```js
var source,
    subscription;

source = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
    // ..

    return function () {
        console.log('disposed');
    };
});

subscription = source.subscribe();

subscription.dispose();
```

```html
<script src='https://rawgit.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/v.2.5.3/dist/rx.all.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `createWithDisposable` wraps the user-supplied `subscribe` function with a `subscribe` that returns a default disposable, whereas `create` requires the user-supplied `subscribe` function explicitly to return a disposable.

Comment: Can you still give some example? I'm still not quite assured if there is some difference :).